The Tragedy of the Episode 749 transcript
The latest (at the time of writing) podcast episode "Tragedy of the (data) commons" seems to have episode notes and no transcripts. For folks who don't do well with audio podcasts, transcripts are useful. As I have in the past - I'd like to request the transcript be made available

There is a transcript now: https://the-stack-overflow-podcast.simplecast.com/episodes/tragedy-of-the-data-commons/transcript

So looks like it's just taking them few days to build/write/generate it. I wonder if it's ever present faster than few days?
