Is speech recognition regarded as genAI on SE (and thereby banned on SE sites banning genAI)?
On The Tragedy of the Episode 749 transcript I had answered (and then commented) that the community had (imho, regrettably) decided to ban genAI here, so one can't post transcripts generated by ASR (speech recognition) systems such as Whisper, since I believe ASR falls under the SE definition of genAI based on meta.stackexchange.com/help/gen-ai-policy:

Content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools” is any content crafted, in part or in whole, using a tool that writes a response automatically based on a prompt it is provided"

However, I see ASR output being posted on Meta.SE, e.g. here, and some ASRs may "hallucinate".
So I'm confused: is speech recognition regarded as genAI on SE (and thereby banned on SE sites banning genAI) or not?

This is a discussion worth having, but the post you linked to is from 2019, way before GenAI was Generally Available Intelligence.

@Glorfindel ok but genAI isn't new to me or anyone working on AI.

Glorfindel's comment is one that adds context here: Back in 2019 was far before the big AI wave that tools like ChatGPT introduced here on SE. I know AI's not new, but the popularity, and the reasons for SE sites banning it, are new.

@Spevacus yes, now that it's become good, let's not use it anymore.

Speech recognition is not generative as defined in the Help Center, because there is no prompt and there is no automatically generated response to that prompt. It is much more a classification problem, i.e., which word corresponds to this 0.5 seconds of audio and which word corresponds to the next 0.5 seconds. Although Whisper is a LLM and it can hallucinate, the output is much more tightly controlled to actually perform the transcription task. It is similar to writing a question in, say, French, and automatically translating it before posting, which is also allowed.

And in general it is important to interpret the ban in the spirit that it was intended, i.e., to prevent flooding the site with content of unknown quality which cannot be handled within the capacity of the human curation systems of the site. Speech recognition clearly does not fall into that category. Asking questions about this is imo a bit disingenuous, as if you try to poke holes into a definition or practise that you don't like by using non-relevant examples.

You might want to note that the post you link is from 2019 and predated the AI ban by years

@Marijn As  you mention, some ASRs "hallucinate" too, so my question is not disingenuous. If you think you're answering, you can write an answer.

I find it interesting that i had the same opinion of AI Generated Content back in 2019 as i do now, given i downvoted it back then. :shrug:

@KevinB WER for SOTA ASRs has decreased a lot since then.

Whatever happened to proofreading? A human who can spend the time to listen and read would only need to spend 1/2 hour checking, then another few minutes correcting (maybe). Is SE so strapped for cash that a misdirected taboo is invoked?

I don't want to policy-craft in the comments but I will say that, even if speech recognition counted as GenAI (which I personally find a bit dubious), I'd find restricting the use of what is transparently an accessibility tool a bit hard to swallow.

i mean.. one can argue AI gen in general is an accessibility tool. :shrug: (people already have, right here on mse)

@W.O. "Whatever happened to proofreading?" -- apparently (judging even from mainstream newspapers) that's an ancient and obsolete thing. Just get it out ASAP to get the clicks. Communicating clearly and coherently? Meh, who needs that. (Although it seems that with the general level of reading comprehension these days, many don't even notice it anyway).

"community had (imho, regrettably) decided to ban genAI " -- what's exactly so regrettable about not allowing machine generated BS being posted on a QA site that prides (well, used to pride) itself on the quality of its content?

@DanMašek see link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/384405/178179

@FranckDernoncourt so by trying to make the ban appear more extreme than what it really is, you want to rally support for removing the ban altogether?

@ShadowWizard No, just trying the understand the ban. Write an answer if you understand the ban.

Is it a theoretical question? Do you have an example of a question or answer where copy-pasting a transcript, or an excerpt of it,  would be useful?

@A.L "Do you have an example of a question or answer where copy-pasting a transcript, or an excerpt of it, would be useful?" yes, see 1st link in my question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/403891/178179

@FranckDernoncourt Was the transcript written by humans? This is only a link to a transcript hosted on a webpage owned by Stack Exchange, about audio generated by SE staff. So this is a very specific case: sharing a link to the SE podcast is fine.

@A.L you posted your answer after I asked the question, so please ignore your answer. "Do you have an example of a question or answer where copy-pasting a transcript, or an excerpt of it, would be useful?" yes, see the question https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/403891/178179/q/404023/178179 which asks for a transcript.

It asked for a transcript of a SE podcast. I think that speech recognition is not useful on SE, with the exception of this specific case. If I knew that an answer to a question could be found in a audio or video recording, I would do the transcript of the important part myself since it would be quicker than processing the whole file. What use case are you thinking of?

@A.L "What use case are you thinking of?"  getting a transcript of a SE podcast with speech recognition

Speech recognition is not generative as defined in the Help Center, because there is no prompt and there is no automatically generated response to that prompt. It is much more a classification problem, i.e., which word corresponds to this 0.5 seconds of audio and which word corresponds to the next 0.5 seconds. Although Whisper is a LLM and it can hallucinate, the output is much more tightly controlled to actually perform the transcription task. Moreover, many other ASR tools are not LLMs at all. It is similar to writing a question in, say, French, and automatically translating it before posting, which is also allowed.
And in general it is important to interpret the ban in the spirit that it was intended, i.e., to prevent flooding the site with content of unknown quality which cannot be handled within the capacity of the human curation systems of the site. Speech recognition clearly does not fall into that category.

well, there is a prompt... there's always a prompt when you have generative ai tweaking the output of another system.

"No explicit prompt by the user of the system" then.

"And in general it is important to interpret the ban in the spirit that it was intended" - I think this is what cinches it for me. We don't like Gen AI because it promotes low-quality, lazy answering. Someone who dictates an entire post cover-to-cover has put effort into it and is likely to check the output, which is very different from someone copy-pasting a ChatGPT response into a text box.

@Anerdw how about someone who dumps a transcript of a 1h podcast?

@Anerdw https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/403891/178179 asked for a transcript of a 0.5h podcast. Why do you think that dumping a transcript from a good ASR is rude/abusive?

@FranckDernoncourt I see, I missed the context. That still seems like a special case to me, though. I get that it’s why this post was written, but to me, the general question of “is speech recognition OK” isn’t the same as “is speech recognition OK for this particular use case.” I’d probably be for the latter; unsure about the former.

@Anerdw yes, an answer may divide these two cases.

While content generated by such a tool isn’t allowed, an answer suggesting its usage as a solution to the company failing to provide a transcript would certainly be allowed.

Thanks! How about adding speech recognition output in a post?

A small sample demonstrating it's capability? maybe? probably not the whole output verbatim.
